# Blog entry in html failing to be processed by php

Tags: php, html

So I have the main blog page "viewBlog.php", and a page where you can add entries "add_entry.html".
The information submitted in add_entry should show in viewBlog, however this is not the case as it just stays blank. I dont know why the information submitted in add_entry is not being processed and echoed on the main div for viewBlog.

add_entry.html code:

```
<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head> <title> Add Entry </title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:antiquewhite;">
<h1 style="color:red; font-family:arial"> Add an entry to Blog! </h1>
  <p>
    Instructions: Enter a title and body for your blog entry. In the body, you can use simple HTML formatting elements, such as &#60b&#62 (bold) and &#60i&#62 (italic) as well as the hyperlink "anchor" element &#60a&#62.
  </p>
<form action="viewBlog.php" method="POST">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Title:
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="title" size="61" maxlength="60">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        Body:
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea name="body" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="Submit" value="Add Entry" name="">
        <input type="reset" onClick="return confirm('Clear the form?');" value="Clear" name="">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

viewBlog.php code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Homepage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="miniCSS.css" title="Style 1" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrap">

<div id="header">
<img src="banner.png" alt="banner" height="150px"/>
</div>

<div id="main">
<?php

$title = $_POST["title"];
$body = $_POST["body"];

echo "$title";
echo "$body";

?>
</div>

<div id="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="viewBlog.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="add_entry.html">Add Entry</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="footer">

</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you echo variables, don't put quotes around them, that converts them to strings (which are echoed literally as `$title` and `$body`). So instead of this

```
echo "$title";
echo "$body";
```

write it that way:

```
echo $title;
echo $body;
```

Comment: should have mentioned I already tried that and still not working. sorry

Comment: But that's the mistake in your code - the way you wrote it above it *can't* work

Comment: Yeah and i had already tried it without the quotes and $title $body still not being echoed.

Comment: Still, before anything else, you have to change that... However, are you opening those files (also the HTML file) via a server (for example `localhost`)? If not, that's the reason:  php code cannot be parsed by simply opening the file in the browser.

Comment: Wow, that was it. I just used localhost on a port and it works. thanks man